# Rally APIs with support for SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, rally

My company is using SSO to login to rally. I have developed a app which uses rally account authorization (BASIC HTTP auth). But since my company ppl are using SSO to login they cannot use their rally login. How to I integrate my existing app with the SSO. Does Rally apis support login using SSO.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the App SDK and other various REST toolkits are not compatible with SSO.

Comment: Is this integration possible now? Is there a link where I could learn more about replacing my auth system with SSO? My company uses SSO . My app is in ruby.